# Alterar as chaves da array retornada pelo mysqli_result

Tags: php, mysql

Preciso de alterar das chaves de um resultado obtido por `mysqli_result->fetch_assoc()`

Se eu fizer esta pesquisa :

```
"SELECT exemplo.nome, exemplo.apelido, exemplo.idade FROM exemplo WHERE exemplo.id=1"
```

recebo este resultado

```
$result["nome"]= "António";
$result["apelido"] = "Silva";
$result["idade"] = "30";
```

e gostaria de receber ou transformar em :

```
$result["exemplo.nome"]= "António";
$result["exemplo.apelido"] = "Silva";
$result["exemplo.idade"] = "30";
```

Não posso usar alias nas frase de pesquisa

```
"SELECT exemplo.nome as exemplo.nome , exemplo.apelido as exemplo.apelido, exemplo.idade  as exemplo.idade FROM exemplo WHERE exemplo.id=1";
```

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Mas porque você quer fazer isso?

Comment: Consegues por "exemplo_nome" se ajudar...

Comment: Pq você não pode usar alias essa coluna é chamada depois?

Comment: Peço imensa desculpa, mas este é o problema que eu tenho. Não adianta questionar porque tem que ser assim. Eu só posso mexer nas chaves do resultado.

Comment: Então você precisa reindexar o array inteiro com esse o prefixo `exemplo`?

Comment: Poderá ser uma solução @rray

Comment: @ManuelGerardoPereira pode criar uma view no banco?

Answer (score 1):

Baseado nessa resposta do [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9605208/1342547) você pode renomear as chaves do array com o prefixo usando [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), o mais recomendado seria utilizar um alias como não é possível, a outra opção seria criar uma view como dito pelo gmsantos.

```
$arr_entrada = array(
            array('nome'=>'joão', 'apelido' => 'j ', 'idade' => '20'),
            array('nome'=>'mario','apelido' => 'm', 'idade' => '28'));

echo'<pre>';
print_r($arr_entrada);


$arr_saida = array_map(function($input) {
    return array(
        'exemplo.nome' => $input['nome'],
        'exemplo.apelido' => $input['apelido'],
        'exemplo.idade' => $input['idade']
    );
}, $arr_entrada);

echo'<pre>';
print_r($arr_saida);
```

[Exemplo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/m2yh-a238)